# How do you reset $PATH without terminal access?

Tags: path

I was installing cpanm on my CentOS 6.6 VM and I tried to change the $PATH so that I can run it.

However, instead of typing,

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/perl5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I typed

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/perl5/bin:%PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and I seemed to have overwritten the $PATH because I can run cpanm but nothing else. No cat, no vim, and no non-builtin commands.

I read somewhere that restarting will reset $PATH so I tried. When I try to login to the GNOME login page, the OS instantly reboots and returns to the login page. So I can't even access the terminal to change settings.

What is happening and how can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the `$PATH` variable tells your shell what directories it should search for any (non-builtin) command you enter. That way, you don't have to type `/usr/bin/vim` each time (→ convenience), and third-party scripts can just run `bash` without needing to know if your particular Linux/UNIX distribution puts it in `/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/bash`, or somewhere else entirely (→ interoperability).

When you want to run something that's not in your `$PATH`, just give your shell the full path to program, e.g. `/usr/bin/vim`.

---

As for GNOME refusing to start: Just switch to a text-based console (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>), log in with your normal username and password, and `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile` from there.

<sub>Oh, and I should probably mention how to get back from there…

Your graphical login manager will normally run on `tty7`, which you can switch to with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As n.st already explained how to fix your $PATH variable, I'll just tell you how to get back a shell access (works with grub) :

1. Reboot your machine. At the grub prompt, select your linux distrib, and press 'e' (for 'edit' at the place of enter. This should bring you to a basic editor.
2. Go to the line beginning by 'linux /boot/...', and append it 'init=/bin/bash' (without quotes). Then press F10 (or the key which is said to be the one to boot, I don't remember exactly which one it is).
3. Your distro will boot straight to bash, in less than a second, with root enabled. You can then re-export your $PATH variable to your bash_profile file (look for examples on the Internet if you don't know it exactly).

When done, you can reboot normally (you shouldn't need to remove the 'init' thing, this should have been done automatically).